# Changing Image of Imagebutton on click,using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onclick, imagebutton

I'm trying to change the image URL when an image button is clicked but the image is not changing.

None of the functions within the javascript change the Image and do not seem to get the ID of the imagebutton.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to make this work?

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <script src="Default.js"></script>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
           <div class="sliderDivImages">
                <div class="buttonContainer">
                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="projectManagementButton" OnClientClick="ButtonClick()" CssClass="button" ImageUrl="Images/button_ProjectPrintManagement.png"></asp:ImageButton>
                    <p class="button">
                        PROJECT &<br />PRINT MANAGEMENT
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>

function ButtonClick() {

    $("<%= projectManagementButton.ClientId %>").attr("src", "Images/buttonLight_ProjectPrintManagement.png");

    var projectManagementImg = document.getElementById("projectManagementButton");

    var imageButtonID = $(this).attr("ID");

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the ID (#) in jquery try:

```
  $("#<%= projectManagementButton.ClientId %>").attr("src", "Images/buttonLight_ProjectPrintManagement.png");
```